# fill HTML label with data attribute without line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mdbootstrap

I create a form where I check the length of a password. If length is <6 then an error message appears.
This message is created by javascript. And here is the problem, the message appears with a line break after every word. I also tried it with ' ' but that doesn't work:(

How do I create the message without the line breaks?

Thanks for your help!

```js
$("#registerPass").on("focusout", function() {

  if ($("#registerPass").val().length < 6) {
    $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    $('#registerPass + label').attr('data-error', 'Mindestens 6 Zeichen nötig!');
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.11/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.11/js/mdb.min.js"></script>



<form style="color: #757575;" action="#!">
  <div class="md-form mb-5">
    <input type="password" id="registerPass" class="form-control" required>
    <label data-error="" data-success="OK" for="registerPass">Passwort</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add width: 100% to the label element. I checked it and updated codebase below.

```js
$("#registerPass").on("focusout", function() {
  if ($("#registerPass").val().length < 6) {
    $(this).removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    $('#registerPass + label').attr('data-error', 'Mindestens 6 Zeichen nötig!');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.11/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.8.11/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

<form style="color: #757575;" action="#!">
  <div class="md-form mb-5">
    <input type="password" id="registerPass" class="form-control" required>
    <label data-error="" data-success="OK" for="registerPass" style="width: 100%">Passwort</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap` to your css and target the `::after` pseudo-element of the label.

https://jsfiddle.net/jvko4wdq/

Alternatively, you may also set the `label` width as `100%`  with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Set 100% width to element, thats it!

```
<label data-error="" data-success="OK" for="registerPass" style='width: 100%'>Passwort</label>
```